# How to save as a new file and keep working on the original one in Vim?

Tags: vim, save, save-as

Whenever I use the `:sav` command, it saves the file with a new name and opens the new file open in Vim.

Is it possible to save the file with a new name but keep the original one open for editing?

Comment: I came with the opposite question.

Comment: @cambunctious Me too. I was googling `vim "save as"` and this question taught me that there is a `:saveas` that works just like I expected: saves the existing file with a new name and opens the new file.

Comment: Great addition! By the way, you can do `:sav` for short and there's also `:sav!` when overwriting an existing file.

Answer (score 576):

Use the `:w` command with a filename:

```
:w other_filename
```

Comment: Furthermore, use `:w %:h/other_filename` to write to a filename in the same directory as the open file.

Comment: @Ioevborg when is that not the case? I just :w fname without reading your comment and the behavior seems to be the default.

Comment: @Cokemonkey11 It's not default behavior in vim to have the current file's location be the same as the working directory. You probably have something in your vimrc file that is doing this for you. Some more information can be found here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file

Comment: I just confirmed that without the "%:h/" the file will be saved in the directory you were in when you opened vim, not where the original file was....

Comment: It may be useful to mention that `:w other_filename` will write data to `other_filename` **only** and not the current file.

Comment: You can see where vim would save by default with `:pwd` and you can change it with `:cd path`

Comment: @loevborg's comment is close but doesn't work for me. I have to use `:w %:p:h/other_filename`.

Comment: @loevborg or `:w %<Tab>` to expand the current name, then edit it

Answer (score 298):

Thanks for the answers. Now I know that there are two ways of "SAVE AS" in Vim.

Assumed that I'm editing hello.txt.

- **:w world.txt**  will write hello.txt's content to the file world.txt while keeping hello.txt as the opened buffer in vim.
- **:sav world.txt** will first write hello.txt's content to the file world.txt, then close buffer hello.txt, finally open world.txt as the current buffer.

Comment: `:sav` won’t close initial buffer, it will hide it. By default, hidden buffers are unloaded, but this can be overriden (with 'hidden' or 'bufhidden' options).

Comment: So, yeah...`:sav` is closer to the "Save as" I've known.

Comment: From Vim's help: `:sav[eas][!] [++opt] {file}` So, `:sav` **is** the shortener for `:saveas`. Whereas, `:w` is the shortcut for `:[range]w[rite][!] [++opt] {file}`. And everything is in the manual, just few lines above/below.

Answer (score 29):

After save new file press

```
Ctrl-6
```

This is shortcut to alternate file

Comment: For what it's worth, using nvim 0.1.0 under OS X 10.10.5, this requires SHIFT-CTRL-6.

Comment: shift-ctrl-6 on a Homebrew version of Vim on OS X 11.

Answer (score 6):

The following command will create a copy in a new window. So you can continue see both original file and the new file.

```
:w {newfilename} | sp #
```