# How to save file under different name in vi

Tags: vi

I am frequently editting a file in `vi` and I want to save it under a different name than the name that I opened it under.

I have tried saving like this:  `:w >> new_file_name` but I ALWAYS get `E212: Can't open file for writing`.

What is the correct way around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save as a new file and keep working on the original one in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980168/how-to-save-as-a-new-file-and-keep-working-on-the-original-one-in-vim)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enter `:w filename` in vi command mode, like @Yedidia said...

I think you are confusing writing terminal output to a file.

Which would be following command in order to **create** or **overwrite** `text.txt`:

```
 action > text.txt
```

and in order to **append** the output of an command to text.txt would be:

```
action >> text.txt
```

Answer (score 27):

```
:w filename
```

Will save to filename